# How is this responsive without media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was going through pure CSS sliders on codepen and I stumbled upon this -> http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
</div>

@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

So how does this achieve responsive design, without the use of @media queries at all? Also how exactly does it manage to control height of the image, even though there is no mention of height or sizing?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, the wrapper of the images has 500% width = 100% * numberOfImages.

Then with CSS it does the slideshow animating the position of that same wrapper, each keyframe = 100% / numberOfSlides.

The height is not defined, it's adjusted proportionally, based on the width of the screen (the 20% you see = wrapper's width / numberOfSlides = 100% of the screen's width)

The final image/container size in terms of height can be controlled by specifying the width itself, as through this approach, the height and width tied to each other.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had tried fiddling with it, and couldn't control the width in proportion to the height which prompted me to ask. Seems that will work if we use float: bottom and then control the height instead. (Also ofcourse, move the keyframes to down rather than left), but then that would loose its general responsive nature. :(

Comment: This is actually by far and hands down the best way to design a fully responsive, maintainable and lightweight slider.
If you are good with keyframes, you can do spectacular things with this approach.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKNwJJ

Comment: @PatrickMedina no , not really since using the -top method, the document looses its normal responsive features as when you consider a resposive document, all you are generally considering is the width of the screen. The height is rarely taken into consideration. 

I wanted the change though for styling reasons, but figured out that I could control that aspect by setting a max-width property on div#slider.

I'm really new on stackoverflow (just a lurker till now). Do mods automatically close threads?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to set the width on the slider div, so it wasn't behaving as expected. Please refer to: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPVYjb. If what you want is for the images to still cover 100% of the screen's width, then another solution must be used